# Magento - Display specific products at the top of a category

Tags: php, magento, product

I need to be able to manually set three 'special' products from each category to display above all the others.

The way I'm thinking of doing it would be to get a product by its ID, and then display it in a static block below the category description.

It would also be preferable to be able to set the products from the back end for the user, but that's not a priority.

I'm not particularly knowledgeable with PHP though, so I would really appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing you are trying to achieve is little tricky here because i think you want:

1. The products to be different in different category page
2. They could be dynamically assigned by the admin

If i am getting you right than you must provide the admin, the place to select the product to the admin in the admin panel.

There are many ways you can do that but i can provide you with the guidelines for one method:

1. You have to create a custom module for admin which list out the products according to the category.
2. You need to let admin select using the checkbox. Create your own table that has field for product sku, category id and other required field.
3. When the admin select the product and save you should save the above mentioned field in that table.

Next thing is to display those product in the frontend. you can add a block of type **core/template** in your category page and assign a template to it.

Now you need to get the current category in that phtml and and filter the products sku from your custom table according to the category.

Now you can use these product sku to load into product model to get the other information about that product.

This is the guidelines.Hope this will help you in some extent.

Comment: Yes, this is essentially what I want to do. I just need to how to do it now. Thanks, that's very helpful.

Comment: I couldn't help you with whole code because it is a standalone module. You can start and if you have some problem post it in this forum you will surely get your answer. If the answer was helpful to you don't forget to vote up n Happy Coding

Comment: That's not a problem, I'm happy to try to figure it out, I have to learn somehow. I would vote up, but apparently I need 15 rep before I can. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

Hi as i understand so far so can use the magento inbuilt function.
In admin under categories there is a option where you can assign a product number according to which they will display on the page.

[image]

please have a look at the screen-shot and you can see there i have assign a number to the products and according to that numbers the product will display on your category page.

thanks hope this will help you.

Comment: I've never noticed that before, it's useful to know. However I don't think it will work for my needs as I need the products to be completely separate from all the others, and styled to show that they are on special offer.

Comment: for that than you need to customize the list.phtml file , you can sort the products by assigning product attribute . But you can mark the answer as helpful if you think it gives you something that can help you. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create new product attribute and sort the product listing collection based on the attribute.

Comment: Hardik, i think that will not fulfill his requirement because he wants to add the special product to each category manually as he wish.